# Cannot solve for an unknown in an equation with exponents

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation I need to solve for `t`. I have tried the code below:

```
Solve[
  51684.2/342077 * 0.048 / 0.148 * 26.09/22.19 == 
    Exp[t/26.09] - Exp[(22.19 t - 26.09 t) / 22.19 * 26.09], 
  t]
```

Wolfram Mathematica keeps calculating forever and never finishes. I have asked for help on the general stack exchange before (not the Mathematica section). They recommended two lines, both of which give a result, but neither is correct. When I manually substitute the value produced by the coded below, they do not satisfy the equation:

```
a = 51684.2/342077 * 0.048/0.148 * 26.09/22.19;
b = Exp[(22.19 t - 26.09 t)/22.19 * 26.09];
FindRoot[a == Exp[t/26.09] - b, {t, 0}]
```

> ```
> {t -> 0.0128273}
> ```

OR

```
NSolve[a == Exp[t/26.09] - b, t, Reals]
```

I believe the answer should be in the the region of 10 – 100, absolutely not below 3.35.

Comment: The value you found with FindRoot does satisfy the equation. `eq = 51684.2/342077*0.048/0.148*26.09/22.19 == 
   Exp[t/26.09] - Exp[(22.19 t - 26.09 t)/22.19*26.09]; sol = FindRoot[eq, {t, 0}]; eq /. sol` yields `True`

Comment: Plot the equation `Plot[Exp[t/26.09] - Exp[(22.19 t - 26.09 t)/22.19*26.09] - 
  51684.2/342077*0.048/0.148*26.09/22.19, {t, 0, 100}]` to check your belief.

Answer (score 3):

You can change this to a minimization problem and the answer returns in seconds:

```
NMinimize[( (51684.2/342077*0.048/0.148*26.09/22.19) - 
            (Exp[t/26.09] - Exp[(22.19 t - 26.09 t)/22.19*26.09]) )^2, t]
{4.93038*10^-32, {t -> 0.0128273}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a real solution you have to tell it `NSolve`:

```
NSolve[51684.2/342077*0.048/0.148*26.09/22.19 ==(Exp[t/26.09] -Exp[(22.19 t - 26.09 t)/22.19*26.09]), t, Reals]
(*{{t -> 0.0128273}}*)
```